# Odoo LDAP module not working correctly between different Server

Tags: ldap, odoo

I want to use Odoo module name: **Authentication via LDAP** (by Odoo SA) to authenticate our user from Active Directory (Server 2003).

On my testing server, everything working smoothly, but not on my production server (I had make sure all settings are the same), this error alway report in server log, although username and password are correct.
[image]

I can not find out why, but when I check the information of LDAP module, I saw a little bit difference:
[image]
[image]

I also tried re-install but nothing change. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is the correct setting working with Odoo v9, I change the port form 389 to **3268**

Comment: You should use template user also.